# Closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^n \cos(nt)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I'm trying to find a closed form (if one exists) for

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^n \cos(nt)$$

where $a \in (0, 1)$.  I know that

$$\begin{matrix} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n} \cos(nt) &= &\ln(a^2-2a\cos(t)+1) \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \cos(nt) &= &2 \ln|2 \sin(\frac{t}{2})| \end{matrix}$$

It feels like these two facts combined should make it relatively easy to come up with the closed form for  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^n \cos(nt)$ but I'm having difficulty seeing it.

Comment: Use the formula for a geometric sum to compute $\sum a^{n} (e^{it})^{n}$ and take the real part.

Comment: Consider $z=ae^{it}$ and $\sum_{0}^{\infty} z^n$ which is a geometric series. The look at the real and imaginary parts. ( Real part gives you your sum I think)

Comment: On another note, looks like differentiating  your first expression with respect to $t$ could help. Though that would give you a sine. So if you had the corresponding sums for sine you could differentiate and obtain the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n\cos(nt)
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(a^ne^{int}+a^ne^{-int}\right)\tag1\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{ae^{it}}{1-ae^{it}}+\frac{ae^{-it}}{1-ae^{-it}}\right)\tag2\\
&=\frac{a\cos(t)-a^2}{1-2a\cos(t)+a^2}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$
$(2)$: sum of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with ratios $ae^{it}$ and $ae^{-it}$
$(3)$: $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$

Comment: You might want to expand on why $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^ne^{int} = \frac{ae^{it}}{1-ae^{it}}$.  I managed to figure it out after a bit of fiddling with the geometric series (which starts at n=0 and not n=1), but it's pretty non-trivial.

Comment: There was discussion of geometric series in the comments to the question that I didn't think to add explanation. Now I have.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $\operatorname{Re} e^{int} = \cos nt$, your series is just geometric. Indeed,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n \cos nt = \operatorname{Re}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(ae^{it}\right)^n.$$
You should then get 
$$\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{ae^{it}}{1-ae^{it}}\right) = \frac{a(a+\cos t)}{1+a^2-2a\cos t}.$$

Comment: I believe that you've multiplied both numerator and denominator by $1-ae^{-it}$, so there should be a minus in the numerator, rather than a plus.