# Infinite Sum of cosine function multiplied by a value to power n

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am willing to find $$\sum_{n \geq 1}r^n \cos(n x)$$ where $x \in (0, 2\pi)$ $r \in (0,1).$ So for $N \in \mathbb{N}$ $$\sum_{n = 1}^Nr^n \cos(nx)=r\cos(x)+r^2\cos(2x)+r^3\cos(3x)+...+r^n\cos(nx)$$

I could not find the partial sum in an facilitated form in order to take the limit. Also, I tried using the exponential form but does not take me away further. I would appreciate any help regard this.

Thank you.

Comment: *Hint*: You have sum of two geometric series, one with common ratio $re^{ix}$ and the other with $re^{-ix}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3706273/42969

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^n \cos(nt)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3706273/closed-form-of-sum-n-1-inftyan-cosnt)

Comment: Yes it does thank you very much